# Can we use sql server stored procedure to call signalr hub?

Tags: sql-server, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub

I have a table that is getting updated from multiple places, so I cannot call signalr hub from those APIs and I have a grid in the UI which I need to refresh wherever the table gets updated, so as a solution I am using Signalr as a message broker.

**Issue**: How can I call the signalr hub when we update the table.

**Solution 1**: One solution I got is to call the signalr hub from the trigger, but its not working for me.
Here is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @httpRequest NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @httpObject NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @httpRequest = N'POST https://localhost:3000/chat HTTP/1.1' + 
                        N'Content-Type:application/json'+
                        N'{"message":"'+@message+'"}';
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @httpObject OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'open', NULL, 'post', @httpRequest, 'false';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'setOption', NULL, 'UseSSL', 'true';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'send';
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @httpObject, 'status';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @httpObject;
```

Is there any better way to solve it?

I tried RabbitMQ as well but the issue remains same, I need to refresh the grid wherever the table gets updated.

Comment: *"Is there any better way to solve it?"* Use CLR, or just *don't* do this in SQL Server at all and use middleware. Those old OA objects are more for compatibility with very old databases (2000/2005).

Comment: Well, as you might know, above implementation  only support SQL Server 2005 and later Edition. In contemporary version it doesn't work for message broker.  [`You can check official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server#prerequisites). [`You can have a look this official implementation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr)

Comment: In addition, [`you can check this sample as well`](https://github.com/upretymadan45/database-change-notification-using-signal-r)